# wordpress query_posts duplicate the number of posts presented

Tags: wordpress, posts

i am building a plugin that would be some kind of a post archive/gallery. i created a veriable that the user chooses the cat ID that will be presented, but from some reason it shows the choosen category twice. any idea on how to fix this ? this is my code:

```
<?php add_action('init', 'process_post'); ?>
<?php query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $cat, 'posts_per_page' => 999));
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?>
<ul class="zeevul"><li>
                    <h2 href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <?php
                if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
                    </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/post-gallery/default-img.png" alt="Image Unavailable" /></a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

<p><?php echo excerpt($words); ?></p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more >></a>
    </li></ul>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
<?php

} 
Function archive()  { return sheker();}
add_shortcode('button', 'button_shortcode');
}
?>
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't say much, but "query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query." - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: why you say it dosn't say much ? this code presents a category i choose. it just dose it twice...

Comment: all i had to add was :"wp_reset_query();" at the end of the query !! and not it works great !!!

Comment: Nice! Well it said enough then.  The top line and the bottom 4 lines are fragments that made it look like a random section of unrelated code to me.

Comment: the top and bottom lines make it work as shortcode!